# Arrange columns using awk or sed?

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file that has around 500 rows and 480K columns, I am required to move columns 2,3 and 4 at the end. My file is a comma separated file, is there a quicker way to arrange this using awk or sed?

Comment: `paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1,5- input.txt) <(cut -d, -f2-4 input.txt)`

Comment: Quicker than what? [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far plus a concise, testable sample input and expected output. ie. provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below solution -

```
perl -F"," -lane 'print "@F[0]"," ","@F[4..$#F]"," ","@F[1..3]"' input.file
```

Comment: It moves 3,4 and 5 to end and removes 2nd.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the columns easily, moving will take too long for 480K columns.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0,$2,$3,$4}' input.file > output.file
```

what kind of a data format is this?

Comment: This is genomic data, we are  testing each individual for 450K positions.

Answer (score 1):

Testing with 5 fields:

```
$ cat foo
1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e
$ cat program.awk
{
    $6=$2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $1  # copy fields to the end and $1 too
    sub(/^([^,],){4}/,"")       # remove 4 first columns
    $1=$5 OFS $1                # catenate current $5 (was $1) to $1 
    NF=4                        # reduce NF
} 1                             # print
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk FS=, OFS=, foo
1,5,2,3,4
a,e,b,c,d
```

So theoretically this should work:

```
{
    $480001=$2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $1
    sub(/^([^,],){4}/,"")
    $1=$480000 OFS $1
    NF=479999 
} 1
```

**EDIT:** It did work.

Comment: My understanding is it's 480,000 columns not 480.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps perl:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join(",", @F[0,4..$#F,1,2,3])' file
```

or

```
perl -F, -lane '@x = splice @F, 1, 3; print join(",", @F, @x)' file
```

Another approach: regular expressions

```
perl -lpe 's/^([^,]+)(,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+)(.*)/$1$3$2/' file
```

---

Timing it with a 500 line file, each line containing 480,000 fields

```
$ time perl -F, -lane 'print join(",", @F[0,4..$#F,1,2,3])' file.csv > file2.csv
40.13user 1.11system 0:43.92elapsed 93%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 67960maxresident)k
0inputs+3172752outputs (0major+16088minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ time perl -F, -lane '@x = splice @F, 1, 3; print join(",", @F, @x)' file.csv > file2.csv
34.82user 1.18system 0:38.47elapsed 93%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 52900maxresident)k
0inputs+3172752outputs (0major+12301minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

And pure text manipulation is the winner

```
$ time perl -lpe 's/^([^,]+)(,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+)(.*)/$1$3$2/' file.csv > file2.csv
4.63user 1.36system 0:20.81elapsed 28%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 20612maxresident)k
0inputs+3172752outputs (0major+149866minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: I ended up writing a Perl script to do this, but I can check this too.

Comment: The latter one for one record with 480000 cols timed using `time` was a bit faster on the average.

Answer (score 1):

Another technique, just bash:

```
while IFS=, read -r a b c d e; do
    echo "$a,$e,$b,$c,$d"
done < file
```